# Ошибка 'function' object has no attribute 'get' При использовании pytest и selenium

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

Никак не могу понять в чем может быть проблема. При запуске кода появляется ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kadenza/PycharmProjects/tenzor1/pages/search.py", line 32, in <module>
    search_page.load()
  File "/home/kadenza/PycharmProjects/tenzor1/pages/search.py", line 23, in load
    self.browser.get(self.URL)
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'

    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
    import pytest
    
    
    @pytest.fixture
    def browser():
        driver = Chrome()
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        yield driver
        driver.quit()
    
    
    class YandexSearchPage:
        URL = 'https://yandex.ru'
        SEARCH_INPUT = (By.ID, 'text')
    
        def __init__(self, browser):
            self.browser = browser
    
        def load(self):
            self.browser.get(self.URL)
    
        def search(self, phrase):
            search_input = self.browser.find_element(*self.SEARCH_INPUT)
            search_input.send_keys(phrase + Keys.RETURN)
    
    
    PHRASE = 'это текст для поиска'
    search_page = YandexSearchPage(browser)
    search_page.load()
    search_page.search(PHRASE)
```

Для проверки попробовал написать такой код и он работает прекрасно.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    driver = Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    yield driver
    driver.quit()


def test_search(browser):
    URL = 'https://yandex.ru'
    PHRASE = 'это текст для поиска'
    browser.get(URL)
    search_input = browser.find_element_by_id('text')
    search_input.send_keys(PHRASE + Keys.RETURN)
```

Comment: как вы вызывали функцию `test_search` ?

Comment: Не буду утверждать, но как я это понял из описания. Благодаря декоратору @pytest.fixture будут вызваны те функции которые начинаются на слово test. Я запускаю код в терминале так "pytest main.py" и функция выполняется сама без вызова

Answer (score 1):

У вас тут маленькая ошибка `search_page = YandexSearchPage(browser)`
Тут вас машина не понимает, 
так как чтобы вызвать функцию надо добавить скобки:
`search_page = YandexSearchPage(browser())`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, так как Вы предлагаете сделать код заработает. Но дело в том, что мне необходимо брать данные о драйвере браузера именно из задекорированной функции. Как в примере с работающим кодом ниже. В таком случае при каждом обращении к браузеру будет выполняться дополнительный нужный код. И по сути сама функция browser возвращает значение Chrome(). То есть как по мне все должно работать)

Comment: Понял вас, тогда ошибка в другом. Щас исправлю но в у меня вилетает ошибка. Типа надо обновить код, возможно её у вас не будет

Comment: Дальше я вам не смогу помочь, потому что не изучал модуль Pytest.

Comment: На самом деле у меня куча ошибок есть которые я не могу объяснить. Например все время просит добавить путь до драйвера браузера в PATH, хотя он уже там. И даже если указывать путь до файла драйвера это не помогает. Написанный код, у меня, без ошибок запускается только из терминала линукс через "pytest main.py"

Comment: У вас драйвер в папке с проектом? Если нет то перенесите его.
+Возможно драйвер который вы скачали не соотвествует версии хрома

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь попробую перенести в папку с проектом. А вот search_page = YandexSearchPage(browser()) не пройдет( уже пробовал, я смотрел в примерах указывается без скобок, видимо благодаря декоратору такое возможно.